# Bold markup not working for Chinese text when exported to html or to pdf output from org-mode

Tags: org-mode, org-export

Here is an example,

```
#+LATEX_CMD: xelatex
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{xltxtra}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \setmainfont{AR PL KaitiM GB}
This is a *test*

这是*测试*
```

The resulted HTML output is the following:

```
<p>
This is a <b>test</b>
</p>

<p>
这是*测试*
</p>
```

I also tried output to PDF, the problem is the same: no effect for the Chinese text.

I also tried the other markup, emphasise, underline, the problem is the same.

I wonder what is the solution for the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the issue isn't with Chinese as such, but with the fact that in Chinese spacing between words isn't obligatory (I think — unfortunately I don't know Chinese), while in Org, by default at least, emphasis markers have to be delimited by whitespace or punctuation.

Hence, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218238/how-to-make-part-of-a-word-bold-in-org-mode) question on stackoverflow is relevant.

There are two solutions presented there: a backend specific one and a more [general one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24540651/6598435).

## Backend specific

This will only work for a specific export format. For instance, for HTML export, you could do this:

```
This is a *test*

这是@@html:<b>@@测试@@html:</b>@@
```

For PDF export:

```
#+LATEX_CMD: xelatex
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{xltxtra}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \setmainfont{AR PL KaitiM GB}
This is a *test*

这是@@latex:\textbf{测试}@@
```

This is obviously extremely inconvenient, unportable and rather ugly.

## General

Quoting from the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24540651/6598435) (as it's extensive and very well explained):

> ```lisp
> (setcar org-emphasis-regexp-components " \t('\"{[:alpha:]")
> (setcar (nthcdr 1 org-emphasis-regexp-components) "[:alpha:]- \t.,:!?;'\")}\\")
> (org-set-emph-re 'org-emphasis-regexp-components org-emphasis-regexp-components)
> ```
>
> #### Explanation
>
> The [manual](http://orgmode.org/manual/Emphasis-and-monospace.html) says that `org-emphasis-regexp-components` can be used to
>
> > fine tune what characters are allowed before and after the markup characters [...].
>
> It is a list containing five entries. The first entry lists characters that are allowed to immediately *precede* markup characters, and the second entry lists characters that are allowed to *follow* markup characters. By default, letters are not included in either one of these entries. So in order to successfully apply formatting to strings immediately preceded or followed by a letter, we have to add `[:alpha:]` (which [matches any letter](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Char-Classes.html#Char-Classes)) to both entries.
>
> This is what the calls to `setcar` do. The purpose of the third line is to rebuild the regular expression for emphasis based on the modified version of `org-emphasis-regexp-components`.

The only slight weakness of this solution is that when you have multiple emphases on a single line (or even adjacent lines), for example:

```
abc*def*ghi jkl*mno*pqr
```

then in the Emacs buffer (in Emacs 24.4 and 26.1), everything between the two emphases will also be spuriously, visually emphasised (i.e. in the example, not only will `def` and `mno` be emphasised, but also `ghi jkl`). However, in the export (both HTML and PDF), the emphasis (bolding) will be correct (i.e. only `def` and `mno` are bold), so it's a minor issue.

Comment: Your diagnostic is right on spot! Yes, it's because of the lack of space in the Chinese characters. I added one space before the markup, then I was able to produce the desired effect for the export to HTML. I still have some problem with export to PDF, it produced no visible bold effect even for the English text. Maybe, the font that I have chosen does not support bold?

Comment: It is possible that your font doesn't support bold. Perhaps you could check by trying to add the explicit LaTeX markup (e.g. `@@latex:\textbf{测试}@@`) or by editing the intermediate `.tex` file and adding the `\textbf{}` there? Also, you could look at the intermediate `.tex` file and check if the relevant text is correctly marked up (for instance with `\textbf{}`).

Comment: You're right. It's a problem with the font. I did see \textbf{测试} in the resulted test.tex, and also tried to use @@latex:\textbf{测试}@@ in test.org, there is no visible bold effect either. Thanks!